# What is an elegant way to drive same APIs on different stacks in C#

Tags: c#, json, testing, tcl

I'm writing a C# test driver for two APIs that support the same functions on different stacks. There about two dozen different functions. I'm generating generic test cases (in JSON) with Spec Explorer, which requires a static target. The generic test cases are mapped to the specific interfaces for input and applied to the interface under test. Then, then output from the IUT is mapped back to a generic JSON format to allow comparison of the response from each API.

I've implemented this with a workable, but inelegant code structure, as following code fragments suggest.

```
public static class TestDriver
{
    private static StackOneAdapter S1Api = new StackOneAdapter();
    private static StackOneAdapter S2Api = new StackTwoAdapter();

    public static void FunctionA(string TestInputs, string ExpectedResults)
    {
        switch (TestMode)
        {
        case TestModes.StackOne:
            S1Api.FunctionA(TestInputs, ExpectedResults);
            break;
        case TestModes.StackTwo:
            S2Api.FunctionA(TestInputs, ExpectedResults);
            break;
        case TestModes.BOTH:
            S1Api.FunctionA(TestInputs, ExpectedResults);
            S2Api.FunctionA(TestInputs, ExpectedResults);
        break;
            case TestModes.NONE:
            break;
        }
    }
    public static void FunctionB(string TestInputs, string ExpectedResults) {}
    ...
    public static void FunctionX(string TestInputs, string ExpectedResults) {}
}

abstract public class Adapter
{
    public abstract string FunctionA(string Input, string ExpectedResult);
    ...
    public abstract string FunctionX(string Input, string ExpectedResult);
}

abstract public class Adapter : StackOneAdapter
{
    public abstract string FunctionA(string Input, string ExpectedResult) 
    {
        // set up call to stack one, function A
        // make the call
        // catch exception
        // serialize the response from stack one, function A and return that
    }
    ...
    public abstract string FunctionX(string Input, string ExpectedResult) {}
}

abstract public class Adapter : StackTwoAdapter
{
    public abstract string FunctionA(string Input, string ExpectedResult) {}
    ...
    public abstract string FunctionX(string Input, string ExpectedResult) {}
}
```

In the past, I've used Tcl for things like this. Instead of hardcoding the same method name, I would have used a variable methodName, defined all the methodNames in a list, and then iterated over that.

I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce the code bulk in C#, similar to what Tcl does. Or does C# strong typing mean that isn't possible? Or if possible, would that be too weird to be practical?

Tia

Comment: Did you try using reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [dynamic type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). You'll need to provide method names and arguments in the code, C# overloading logic will be used, but with late binding.

```
dynamic foo = GetFoo();
foo.Method(arg1, arg2);
```

If it's not dynamic enough, use [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) ([ImpromptuInterface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface)). You'll be able to call methods by name and construct arguments at run time. C# overloading logic will be used.

```
object foo = GetFoo();
Dynamic.InvokeMember("Method", new object[]{ arg1, arg2 });
```

Or you can just use good old [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx). You'll resolve methods the way you want, at run time.

```
object foo = GetFoo();
foo.GetType().GetMethod("Method").Invoke(foo, new object[]{ arg1, arg2 });
```